# Case Emails - Thread ID - Replies coming back to the case

Tags: administration, email2case, email-alert, case

I've been researching online to verify this, and then tested this morning, and I'm confused as to why it works this way.  Could someone please verify if I'm just missing some extra step?

An email sent via an **email-to-case** automated reply to the Client, with a **ThreadID** on the subject line, allows the Client to REPLY to the email and that reply ends up on the Case in Salesforce.  *Good*.

An email sent (workflow or otherwise?) from the Case, with the ThreadID on the subject line, does NOT allow the Client to reply and have that comment return to the case.  *Bad*.

Am I just missing something extra I need to do??  :-(   Why have ThreadID and ONLY allow it to work with email-to-case emails??

EDIT:  An [online reference](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bpy9) to this issue.

EDIT 2:  **I've half answered the question through more research**.  The thread_id works FINE for getting the message back to SF if the FROM field is properly set.  If the FROM field is someone's personal email, the reply never GOES BACK to SF.  If, however, the FROM field is set to either the long-address for SF email-to-case, or more easily to the email that is you have FORWARDING to that long address (techsupport@xyz.com let's say), then SF gets the email, sees the Thread on the Subject, and sends it to the Case it belongs to.

**THE QUESTION THEN BECOMES** (still reearching):  Can we make the "default" FROM address on each Case Record Type be a specific email address?

The closest I see to this is in the Email Alerts area, ("Make this address the default From email address for this object's email alerts") but that affects all email alerts based on waht I know.. not "which FROM address" would be used if they click Send Email in a Case.

Comment: Have you looked at your case escalation rules as one possibility for the cause?

Comment: No.  It never occurred to me that this would have any bearing (?!).  I'll research that...

Comment: I'm not finding any reference telling me that Escalation has anything to do with Thread_ID usage.

Comment: I've got the question half-resolved through research, just need to see how to make the "Default" FROM field when you click Send Email in a Case be a specific address (notes added to Question above).

Comment: AFAIK you can't set a default FROM address per record type, out of the box. It is possible that org-wide addresses would allow your users to select an address when they sent it, if that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question mostly answered in text of Question itself (Edits).  New question coming regarding issue with Button code being written to default the "From" field to a specific address.

[Case Emails - Custom Button - TO field not populating properly](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10217/case-emails-custom-button-to-field-not-populating-properly)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can set a default From address in Service Cloud if you are using Case Feed.

See Richard's answer here https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kdRmAAI and documentation here https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=case_interaction_settings.htm&siteLang=en_US