# Case Emails - Custom Button - TO field not populating properly

Tags: email, administration, custom-button, case, custom

```
https://na4.salesforce.com/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?
p3_lkid={!Case.Id}&retURL=%2F5{!Case.Id}&
p26=cs@markettraders.com:Customer%20Service
```

I have gone back and forth with this code, and cannot figure out why p3_lkid is not populating.  The page that opens  (relevant references) has:

```
<input type="hidden" name="p3_lkid" id="p3_lkid" value="5006000000PKSst" /><input type="hidden" name="p3_lkold" id="p3_lkold" value="00044430" /><input type="hidden" name="p3_lktp" id="p3_lktp" value="500" /><input type="hidden" name="p3_lspf" id="p3_lspf" value="0" /><input type="hidden" name="p3_lspfsub" id="p3_lspfsub" value="0" /><input type="hidden" name="p3_mod" id="p3_mod" value="0" /><span class="lookupInput"><input  id="p3" maxlength="255" name="p3" onchange="getElementByIdCS('p3_lkid').value='';getElementByIdCS('p3_mod').value='1';" size="20" title="Related To" type="text" value="00044430" /><a href="javascript:%20openLookup%28%27%2F_ui%2Fcom.................
```

It LOOKS populated, right?  But here's the screenshot:

[image]

Help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the wasted post.  It figures that shortly after I post this, I dug some more and realized I was NOT populating the actual "TO" field.  Fixed code below.  Added p2_lkid element.

```
https://na4.salesforce.com/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?
p3_lkid=!Case.Id}&retURL=%2F5{!Case.Id}&
p26=cs@markettraders.com:Customer%20Service&
p2_lkid={!Case.AccountId}
```

Comment: Hey @AMM, I'm attempting to do the same - populate the To and Related To field from the Send Email button.
I set both the p3_lkid for Related To and p2_lkid for To but I get an error saying I'm unable to access page because a parameter contains an invalid character or exceeds max length. Can I ask if you ran into this problem with your solution? The URL you have is pretty much exactly what I need and have with the exception of your CC field.